# custome validation on laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Checking one date is greater the other then want to throw error message in laravel 4

```
if($_POST['TP_cab_travel_date_return'] < $_POST['TP_cab_travel_date'])
{
    $rules['TP_cab_travel_date_return'] = 'required';   
    $messages = array( 'TP_cab_pickup_address.required' => 'Return date should
                        be less than start date.');
}
```

Comment: What format are these dates in? If `YYYY-MM-DD` then maybe that will work.

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Also if you're using Laravel you shouldn't be using `$_POST` directly, but instead the [Request object](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel Validation to check stat and end date like below, `$request` variable get the post values in laravel

Here i mentioned the date format is `Y-m-d`
You need to include `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` to use the `Request` object

```
  public function myfunc(Request $request)

           $this->validate($request,[
                'TP_cab_travel_date'=>'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
                'TP_cab_travel_date_return'=>'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after:TP_cab_travel_date', 
            ]);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use **strtotime()** php function check here [function.strtotime.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
like this

```
if(strtotime($_POST['TP_cab_travel_date_return']) < strtotime($_POST['TP_cab_travel_date']))
{
    $rules['TP_cab_travel_date_return'] = 'required';
    $messages = array( 'TP_cab_pickup_address.required' => 'Return date should
            be less than start date.');
}
```

Comment: Yes but it directly submit the form and validation is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the validator itself:

```
 $rules['TP_cab_travel_date_return'] = 'required|date_format:m-d-Y|after:TP_cab_travel_date';

  $messages = array( 'TP_cab_pickup_address.after' => 'Return date should
                    be less than start date.');
```

Note: date_format is necessary to work properly